# How to prove an ideal is prime in $R[x]$ when $R$ is not an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For example, consider the ring $(\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z})[x]$, and an ideal $(x^2+x+1)$. I can show that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible, but it cannot imply that it is prime.  I am not sure if $(x^2+x+1)$ is prime. Is there a simple way to show this?

Comment: In the quotient of your polynomial ring with the ideal generated by $x^2+x+1$, we still have $2\times 3 = 0$. However, neither $2$ nor $3$ is zero in the quotient, can you prove this ?

Comment: @Suzet Oh, so does it mean that no polynomial is prime? because $\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}[x]/(f)$ is always not an integral domain.

Comment: This isn't true neither : for instance, if $f = 2x+1$ then $3$ belongs to the ideal generated by $f$ (given that $3f = 3$). The reason why it works well in the case of $x^2+x+1$ is because it is monic.

Comment: @Suzet Oh right. Thank you! For cases like $f=2x+1$, when $2$ or $3$ is zero in the quotient ring. Is it true that $f$ is prime? how can we prove it?

Comment: Yeah, $f=2x+1$ is prime, as the quotient of $(\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z)[x]$ by $f$ will then be isomorphic to $\mathbb F_3[x]/(2x+1)$, which is a domain (on the polynomial ring $\mathbb F_3[x]$ with coefficients being in a field, we now have a good notion of degree, thanks to which $2x+1$ is easily seen to be irreducible, hence prime).

Comment: @Suzet Thank you! So there is a final question. Given a polynomial $f$, how do we know if 2 or 3 is zero in the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}[x]/(f)$? Does $f$ always have the form $q(x)+1$ where $q(x)$ is some polynomial with no constant and other coeffients $=2$or $3$?

Comment: I'm unsure if we can get such a criterion. The constant coefficient of $f$ needs not be $1$, it just need to divide the constant you consider. The question would be, if a constant zero divisor ($2$,$3$ or $4$) is in the ideal generated by $f$, then all non constant coefficients of $f$ are also zero divisors. It certainly is true for the leading coefficient ; I don't know what we can say in all generality..